# typeof(T) within generic nested types

Tags: c#, generics, typeof, type-parameter

I don't understand why the following behaves the way it does at all. I don't even know if it's caused by hiding or something else.

```
class A<T>
{

    public class B : A<int>
    {
        public void b()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).ToString());
        }
        public class C : B
        {
            public void c()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).ToString());
            }
        }
        public class D : A<T>.B
        {
            public void d()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A<string>.B.C c = new A<string>.B.C();
        A<string>.B.D d = new A<string>.B.D();
        c.c();
        c.b();
        d.d();
        d.b();
    }
}
```

The questions are:

1. Why does `c.c()` produce System.String while `c.b()` produces `System.Int32`?
2. Why does `d.d()` and `d.b()` both produce `System.String` and not behave in exactly the same way as the class `C`?

Comment: Seems like this code is deliberately obfuscated.  The solution is to not write code like this in the first place.

Comment: @Servy: Presumably, it's an exercise, not intended for practical consumption, but merely learning.

Comment: @RobertHarvey SO is designed for *practical* programming problems however, so if that's the case, it would make it offtopic, no?

Comment: @Servy Someone may end-up *generating* such code for whatever *practical* reasons.

Comment: I'd be surprised if anyone would have a legitimate reason to use this mess of nested classes in any practical code (generated or not).

Comment: @Servy: You can't require every Stack Overflow question to be tied to some specific project the asker is currently working on.  The requirement is that the question have *practical considerations*.

Comment: Unless that legitimate reason is to teach a student how code works, in which case this question is wrong for a different reason. If this is simply obfuscated to hide business logic (which it may be too simple for) then whatever.

Comment: Practical or not, I'm currently stumped :( Personally I think this kind of question is great for growing people's ability to read the specification, which is useful in itself.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/07/27/an-inheritance-puzzle-part-one.aspx

Comment: @SLaks: That's what I thought of immediately when I saw this, but this result doesn't follow from what I saw there, because both C and D are B, and in B, T is Int32.

Comment: Jon Skeet stumped?? Question: upvoted.

Comment: @Servy, yes, I understand it's obfuscated and I tried but I couldn't reduce its complexity without removing the question. If I removed some of the things (an inheritance here or there), the answer could have stayed the same but for different reasons.

Comment: This guy is wizard for causing @JonSkeet to be stumped.

Comment: @PetrHudeček That's my *point*.  If you simplify the question to code that someone would legitimately write, you wouldn't have a problem to begin with.  It's only observable from code that really shouldn't be used.  It's a confusing concept because it's a situation one the language designers didn't really expect people to be in to begin with, and so didn't optimize for.

Comment: Confusing and complicated is an understatement for this question!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a variation of a puzzle that I posted on my blog many years ago:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/07/27/an-inheritance-puzzle-part-one.aspx

and Cyrus posted on his blog before that:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cyrusn/archive/2005/08/01/446431.aspx

See the discussion there for details.

Briefly: what does `B` mean in `class C : B` ? Check the container, `class B`. Does it contain any type called `B`?  No.  Then check the container's base class. The container's base class is `A<int>`. Does it contain anything called `B`? Yes.  So this means `class C : A<int>.B`.

Now we say that `c` is `A<string>.B.C`.  We call method `A<string>.B.C.c()` What is `T` throughout `A<string>`?  Obviously `string`.  So `c.c()` prints `String` for `T`.

Now we call `A<string>.B.C.b()` but there is no such method in `A<string>.B.C` directly. Where does it get this method? From its base class. What's it's base class? `A<int>.B`.  So we call `A<int>.B.b()`. What is `T` throughout `A<int>`?  Obviously `int`.

Now we come to `A<string>.B.D.d()`.  The base class is irrelevant. `T` is `string` throughout `A<string>`.

And finally `A<string>.B.D.b()`.  There is no such method on `A<string>.B.D` directly so it must get it from its base type. `T` is `string` throughout `A<string>`, so the base type is `A<string>.B`. Therefore this calls `A<string>.B.b()`.

If that doesn't make sense to you, spell everything out. Let's substitute String for T:

```
class A_string
{
    public class B : A_int
    {
        public void b()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(string).ToString());
        }
        public class C : A_int.B // Note!
        {
            public void c()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(typeof(string).ToString());
            }
        }
        public class D : A_string.B
        {
            public void d()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(typeof(string).ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OK, that's one of the types. Now let's do the same for int:

```
class A_int
{
    public class B : A_int
    {
        public void b()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(int).ToString());
        }
        public class C : A_int.B // Note!
        {
            public void c()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(typeof(int).ToString());
            }
        }
        public class D : A_int.B
        {
            public void d()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(typeof(int).ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now given those types it should be clear what `A_string.B.C.c()`, `A_string.B.C.b()`, etc, all print out.

Comment: And -- this is also because we first look up methods in base class before we go to outer class, right?

Comment: @PetrHudeček: We look up *names* in base classes before outer classes.

Comment: @PetrHudeček: Not methods, but base types.

Comment: @SLaks: What do you mean? I meant... when, in the Main method, we are looking for c.b() where c is as A<string>.B.C, but we cannot find the method b in the class itself, then we may either look in its base class (which is A<int>.B) or its outer class (which is A<string>.B). Looking in base class is preferred by the compiler, I understood.

Comment: @PetrHudeček: Wrong.  Instance members are never looked up from outer classes; after all, you don't actually have an instance of the  outer class to call it on.  The question here is about _type_ lookup in the base declaration; does `B` mean `A<int>.B` (inherited from the base type's outer class as `A<string>.B.B`) or `A<string>.B` (inherited fromn the outermost class)

Answer (score 3):

`A<string>.B.C` inherits `A<int>.B`, because `B` in the base class declaration comes from the inside parent scope first.  (to clarify, its parent scope is `A<T>.B`, which contains a type named `B` referring to `A<int>.B`, inherited from its base class `A<int>`)

Calling `b()` comes from its base class, in which `T` (from the parent scope) is `int`.

`D` explicitly inherits `A<T>.B`, using `T` from the outermost scope (`A<T>`), so its `T` always comes from `A<>` in its typename.

Comment: The most recent edit explains it. It does make me wonder if the other `T` is somehow accessible though.

Comment: @Magus: Within the base class methods in `B`, there _is no_ other type; generic type parameters are not polymorphic.

Comment: `c.GetType()` is `A\`1+B+C[System.String]`; its `BaseType` is `A\`1+B[System.Int32]`.

Comment: It's D that causes me confusion. It must be an A<string>.B<int>, right? But the int is not accessible?

Comment: @MagusL No. `B` is not generic.  Type parameters are not inherited by derived class. `T` inside `B` refers to `T` from `A<T>` from the parent scope.  The first one was different because it was actually `A<int>.B`.

Comment: @Magus: No, there is no such thing as `A<string>.B<int>` because `B` isn't generic to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very slightly more complex example of a puzzle Eric Lippert describes in [this blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/07/27/an-inheritance-puzzle-part-one.aspx), which is then explained in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/07/30/an-inheritance-puzzle-part-two.aspx).

The short summary (I highly suggest just reading the article) is that in this case there is an ambiguity in the line `C : B`.  A decision needs to be made as to what `B` actually means in this context; whether it's `A<T>.B` or `A<int>.B`.  Essentially, the compiler chooses the latter, given a particular criteria of "betterness" described in the spec.